# Windows 8 Tortoise SVN connection issue

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

Trying to configure a new machine, and when attempting to checkout a repository with tortoise svn, I get the following error:

> Checkout from
>   svn+ssh://tim@dev.activemls.com/home/activemls/svn_repository/AMLS_frontend/trunk,
>   revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included Unable to connect
>   to a repository at URL
>   'svn+ssh://tim@dev.activemls.com/home/activemls/svn_repository/AMLS_frontend/trunk'
>   To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from
>   'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
>   Network connection closed unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

You should try using basic svn protocol first to see if this is just an SSH issue or a more basic problem.